# vb.net get local resource name from control property

Tags: vb.net

How can i get the **name** of a **local resource** that has been assigned to a control property like `BackgroundImage`?

For example, i have a button and i have set the `BackgroundImage` property to a local resource image.

What i want, is at **runtime** to get the **name** of the **local resource** that has been assigned to `BackgroundImage` of that button.

Comment: Resources stored in the form's .resx file don't have identifier names.  Just an encoded name in the XML that's based on the control name.  The ApplyResource() method knows how to locate the control instance from that encoded string.  Look in the .resx file.  Works just in one direction of course, this is an XY question.

Comment: @HansPassant then what are all these? http://i.imgur.com/98u3des.png these **are** the names of my local resources. this (see that picture first) `a_button.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.error_button24BUTTON_DISABLED` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Well, that's not a "local resource".  Still very little joy going from the Image back to the My.Resources property, you get a new image object every time you use the property.  Avoid the XY question, this just isn't the way you'd ever want to solve a problem.  We don't know the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant if that is not a local resource then what is it? i should update my question details to what? :/ is that information available only to visual studio editor? that popup list makes me *feel* i can get the name somehow.

Comment: *why* do you need to get back what you've assigned?

Comment: @Plutonix toggle between different images, so i can assign to the control's `BackgroundImage` the whatever_ENABLED ---> whatever_DISABLED by replacing "ENABLED" with "DISABLED" using `My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("THE_CORRECT_NAME_OF_THE_RESOURCE_HERE")` to load the "local resource" (or whatever is called)

Comment: You can technically auto-generate the property name from the control's Name and Enabled properties, then use Reflection to find the My.Resources property value.  That is however *very* brittle, a slight mistake will crash your code.  Very ugly when that happens at design time a year from now.  The proper way is to derive a class from Button and add a "DisabledImage" property.  Now you can set it at design time without writing code for every button and you'll never get it wrong later.

Comment: @HansPassant @Plutonix yes the derived class looks good practice. well, i decided to go for a quick fix: i make the images 3 times bigger in width and height, having the "enabled version" up-left on the image (displays with `BackgroundImageLayout=ImageLayout.None`)` and the "disabled version" at the center of the image (displays with `BackgroundImageLayout=ImageLayout.Center)`... oh well...`css-sprites` are haunting me. Should i delete the question? Does it make any sense? Also thank you for your time guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your image:

[image]

you can see two things about the way your resources are handled.  First, the return is a `Bitmap`, so once assigned to a button or whatever, you would have a very hard time determining what it is from the image data.  The second thing is that the identifiers are actually `Properties` not just tokens or keys into a collection. The IDE generates these in your `Resources.Designer.vb` file to provide access to the various resources. Here is the interface to get the bitmap of the French Flag from the resource designer file:

```
Friend ReadOnly Property FRFlag() As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Get
        Dim obj As Object = ResourceManager.GetObject("FRFlag", resourceCulture)
        Return CType(obj,System.Drawing.Bitmap)
    End Get
End Property
```

Yours will have things like `Property error_button24BUTTON_DISABLED`.  Like any other property, the name of the property is not part of the return, just the data associated with them.

Since what really matters is the **state** of the button, not the image being shown, and that Enabled state is very easy to evaluate, not much is lost just using an if statement:

```
 If thisButton.Enabled Then
      thisButton.BackGroundImage = My.Resources...
 Else
      thisButton.BackGroundImage = My.Resources...
 End If
```

You would have had to do something like this to convert "True" for Enabled to "BUTTON_ENABLED" to create the resource "key" if it actually worked the way you thought it did, or was intent on getting it via Reflection.

There are several alternatives.  One might be to write an `ExtenderProvider` to provide various state images for the controls you are working with, subclass them or just use a local Dictionary/HashTable like an Extender would:

```
Friend Class ButtonImages
    ' ToDo: load these from My.Resources in the ctor for a given button
    ' ...
    Private Property EnabledImage
    Private Property DisabledImage

    Public Function GetStateImage(b As Boolean) As Bitmap
        If b Then
            Return EnabledImage
        Else
            Return DisabledImage
        End If
    End Function

End Class

Private myBtnImgs As New Dictionary(of Button, ButtonImages)

thisButton.BackgroundImage = myBtnImgs(thisButton).GetStateImage(thisButton.Enabled)
```

It is more involved than a simple If statement, but comes close to what you seem to have been looking for.

Comment: i need to re-phrase my question to include my original goal (so question makes sense without having to read the comments), i will do it later and accept this answer, thank you!